# Как установить стартовую позицию тексту в контейнере со скроллом?

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка

[image: Красная линия - желаемая стартовая позиция текста]

В общем-то вопрос в том, можно ли задать стартовую позицию для текста в контейнере с возможностью сролла, так чтобы при скролле текст уходил вверх за эту линию?

Answer (score 2):

Догадался сам :)

Можно создать пустой див прямо перед текстом и задать ему размеры.
Возможно это не самый хороший вариант, но все же работает как я и хотел.